# Äquivalent zu "kicking and screaming"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Gibt es ein Äquivalent zu "kicking and screaming" = "doing something unwillingly"? Dict.cc schlägt "[Unter großen Protest](http://www.dict.cc/?s=kicking%20and%20screaming)" vor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Heulend und zähneknirschend machte er sich an die Arbeit

oder

> Er machte sich unter Heulen und Zähneknirschen an die Arbeit

"Unter großem Protest" finde ich ein bißchen sehr förmlich im Vergleich zum englischen Original.

Comment: Ich auch. Danke!

Comment: Kicking and screaming klingt nach Gegenwehr bis zum Äußersten, dagegen ist Heulen und Zähneknirschen ein Ausdruck der Resignation.

Answer (score 9):

> Er wehrte sich mit Händen und Füßen.

oder, wenn man z.B. seinen Besitz verteidigt:

> Er wehrte sich mit Klauen und Zähnen.

Ich kenne das englische "kicking and screaming" mehr im Zusammenhang von unter lautem Protest zu etwas gezwungen werden als bloß es unwillig zu tun.

Heulen und Zähneknirschen wäre IMHO besser als "[there was a] great wailing and gnashing of teeth" übersetzt.